# Replace mutation target text node with a span element

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, mutation, createelement, textnode

I am using MutationObserver to track character changes in my rich text editor. Everytime a text is edited, the mutation callback method is called with the list of mutation records. The mutation target is the text node in which changes are made. I want to wrap this text node with a span so that I can use some css to highlight changed text. However, this is not working for me. Can you please guide what am I doing wrong here?

```
function callback(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        if(mutation.type == 'characterData'){
           let parentNode = mutation.target.parentElement;

           // Create the new node to insert
           let newNode = document.createElement("span");
           newNode.classList.add('change-highlighter');

           // appending existing text node to new span element
           newNode.appendChild(mutation.target);

           // inserting newNode before text node
           parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, mutation.target);         
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would insert the span, then append the target.

```js
function callback(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
        if(mutation.type == 'characterData'){
           let parentNode = mutation.target.parentElement;

           // Create the new node to insert
           let newNode = document.createElement("span");

           newNode.classList.add('change-highlighter');

           // inserting newNode before text node
           parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, mutation.target);

           // appending existing text node to new span element
           newNode.appendChild(mutation.target);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! In my case, the previousSibling is also null, so it goes to ```parentNode.appendChild(newNode);``` However, I see bunch of mutation records being printed after made a text change, which are in the following sequence - Text node removed, span node added, remove text node under span, span node added and span node removed. The text I typed is getting moved automatically to a wrong position

Comment: Perhaps it's a lot more simple than I thought. you can insert the span, before the target, then add the target to the span.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives the same behaviour. Here's the complete code that I am trying to run on w3school https://github.com/saurabhkulkarni26/testcode/blob/main/mutationobserver_test.js

Comment: The editor is automatically removing the span from the DOM, so I don't think this is possible with the editor you are using.

Comment: You were right.  The editor was the problem. I used a different editor and now it does not remove those nodes automatically. Thanks a lot!